# How to change UILabel width based on text length in iOS Using Auto-Layouts

Tags: ios, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I want to display two  `UILabel`'s, however `UILabel`'s having variable text length's According to textsize `UIlabel`'s width need to increase using auto-layouts.

For this I wrote below auto-layouts for both `UIlabel`'s

**First Label:**

```
1)leading Space 
2)Top space
3)Width
4)height
5)Horizontal spacing
```

**Second Label:**

```
1)Trailing space
2)Top space
3)Width
4)height
```

how can we do this ?

Please help me.

### my code:

```
textLabel1.numberOfLines = 0
        textLabel1 .sizeToFit()
        textLabel1.text = "asdfdsfdghjgjhkhkjlhjkhjk"

textLabel2.numberOfLines = 0
        textLabel2 .sizeToFit()
        textLabel2.text = "asdfdsfdghjgjhkhkjlhjkhjk"
```

Comment: if you need `uilabel` extend width only?

Comment: yes based on text size need to extends

Comment: can you see your design XIB or storyboard?

Comment: i am using story board

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the First `UILabel`, set Leading, Top, bottom and set fixed width, then go to **size Inspector** -> select **fixed width constraints** -> **Relation** -> select **Greater than or equal**, example is give below,

[image]

[image]

select the Second `UILabel`, set Leading, Bottom, fixed width, then above same processs to be perform,

hope its helpful

Comment: Greater Than or Equal means if your label width is 42, if you set greater than or equal to extend full screen width based upon your text, its extent larger width >= 42, but its fixed 42 and above only.

Comment: Less Than or Equal means if your label width is 240 and is fixed, if you set less than or equal, 240 is maximum value but your text is small, its automatically change the width size based upon your text. if your text above 240 its not visible full text,

Comment: Less Than or Equal example is chatting App, Whats App, any Chatting check it. ok you understand and above constraints working or not

Comment: hi i am having one small dought u thre?

Comment: Tell me what is your dought?

Comment: As i said above i have two labels that's all-right if i given trailing space for UIlabel 2 then width and height both are increasing based on Lable's text size is it possible?

Comment: i hope u understand my dought?

Comment: If you give trailing space, its have some issues, if you give long text its ok, but if you give two word text its allocate full width of the screen, check set background color in `uilabel`. you understand my answer?

Comment: No i can't see this link or image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114587/discussion-between-krish-and-iyyappan-ravi).

Answer (score 0):

Fist you need to set `UILabel`'s property `numberOfLines` to zero and set  text wrapping to word wrap. And after that give the required constraint.

If you are not getting desired result then you need to calculate the label's dynamic height by `boundingRectWithSize:...` method and give height constraint accordingly.